# Define a function in MATLAB

Tags: error-handling, undefined, integration

I wrote down a code to calculate the integral `ParEa` in terms of a function `J` as follows:

```
Laa = 0.01;
ja = 1;
De = 0.001;
J = @(Oma) ja.* Oma .*exp(-Oma/Laa);
ParEaa = @(Oma) pi.^(-1).*J./(Oma.*(Oma + De));
IParEaa = integral(ParEaa, 0, inf)
```

But it gives the errors:

> Undefined function or method 'integral' for input arguments of
>     type 'function_handle'.
>
> Error in ==> sample at 9
>   IParEaa = integral(ParEaa, 0, inf)

I want to calculate the integral without substituting the explicit expression of `J` into `ParEa`? How should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're mixing up the symbolic and numeric integration. 
I cannot check with Matlab but I would suggest the following:

For numerical simulation:

```
J = @(Oma) ja.* Oma .*exp(-Oma/Laa);
ParEaa = @(Oma,J) pi.^(-1).*J./(Oma.*(Oma + De));
IParEaa = integral(ParEaa, 0, inf)
```

For the symbolic integration:

```
syms oma
expr = pi^(-1)*(ja*Oma*exp(-Oma/Laa))/(Oma*(Oma + De));
int(expr,oma,0,inf)
```

I hope it works,
Michael

Comment: Thank you. But the numerical simulation gives the same error. As for the symbolic integration, I don't want to substitute the function.

Comment: Hello,
I hope it is still relevant. I checked the numerical one and I think it is better to substitute J into ParEaa. In this way the function is only depending on one variable.

For the symbolic one, why don't you want to substitute?

In general do you want to have only a "value" or do you want to have the whole expression?

Micha

Comment: Hey,

I finally had the chance to check with Matlab. The following code runs on my machine:

`Laa = 0.01;
ja = 1;
De = 0.001;
J = @(Oma) ja.* Oma.*exp(-Oma./Laa);
ParEaa = @(Oma) pi^(-1).*J(Oma)./(Oma.*(Oma + De));
IParEaa = integral(ParEaa, 0, inf)`